# Simplifying an expression with absolute values

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

I am trying to simplify the function $D(\alpha,\beta)$ shown below (with $\alpha,\beta>0):$

$$ D(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{1+\alpha+2\beta}{2} + \frac{|\alpha-1|}{2} - 2 \left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{|2\alpha-1|}{2}+\beta}{2}+\frac{|\beta-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{|2\alpha-1|}{2}|}{2}\right)-2 \left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-\frac{|\beta-\alpha|}{2}\right)=0$$

This is how I proceed

${\it Case 1: }$ $$\alpha-1>0 \hspace{1cm}\text{and}\hspace{1cm}  \beta-\alpha>0 $$ $$D(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{1+\alpha+2\beta}{2} + \frac{\alpha-1}{2} - 2 \left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2\alpha-1|}{2}+\beta}{2}+\frac{\beta-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2\alpha-1}{2}}{2}\right)-2 \left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}\right) $$

$$\rightarrow \alpha=\beta$$

${\it Case 2: }$ $$\alpha-1<0 \hspace{1cm}\text{and}\hspace{1cm} 2\alpha-1<0\hspace{1cm}\text{and} \hspace{1cm}  \beta-\alpha<0 $$
$$ D(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{1+\alpha+2\beta}{2} + \frac{1-\alpha}{2} - 2 \left(\frac{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1-2\alpha}{2}+\beta}{2}+\frac{|\beta-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1-2\alpha}{2}|}{2}\right)-2 \left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}-\frac{-\beta+\alpha}{2}\right)=0$$

${\it Case 3: }$ $$\alpha-1<0 \hspace{1cm}\text{and}\hspace{1cm} 2\alpha-1>0\hspace{1cm}\text{and} \hspace{1cm}   \beta-\alpha<0 $$

and so on..

As you can see its quite tedious, I want to ask, do you think my approach is correct or am I doing stuff wrong? Is this the only way for me?

Comment: [looks like](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Simplify+1%2Ba%2B2*b%2B%7Ca-1%7C-2%281%2B%7C2*a-1%7C%2B2*b%2B%7C2*b-1-%7C2*a-1%7C%7C%29-2*%28a%2Bb-%7Cb-a%7C%29%3D0) the case by case study is the only way...

Comment: Thanks, can you tell how many cases there are? @Surb

Comment: Note that you should consider $2D(\alpha,\beta)=0$ (this will simplify your expression). For the cases: $3$ different and "independent" absolute values, so $2^3=8$ cases. If I'm not doing a mistake. Actually it's a little less as you have already noticed that $\alpha-1>0$ implies $2\alpha>1$. Note also that you should consider the cases $\alpha-\beta \geq 0$ and $\alpha-\beta< 0$ (do not forget the equality case)

Comment: Great thanks Surb !@Surb